# BlockingCollection and Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, blockingcollection

I have a question about writing codes using BlockingCollection and Dictionary.

My goal is to read a bunch of text files and process them in a parallel fashion. The processed data would be stored in a BlockingCollection instance so that these processed data can be written to a file.

The reason why I want to use the BlockingCollection is ...

(1) to save time while the GenerateDataFiles() is doing CPU-intensive work and the consumer Task can do IO related work in the meantime, and

(2) to reduce memory usage compared to the case when I store all the processed data in a list before writing any of them to a file.

For (2), if I store all data before writing them to a file, the memory consumption is more than my desktop can afford (since it reads more than 30GB of data), and so I have to use this producer-consumer approach.

Also, I got a problem in inserting the key-value pair in the BlockingCollection instance (or dictionary). Please indicate the correct approach to do the data insertion.

The following codes are my attempt to address the problem. I may have made some mistakes in this since I am new to BlockingCollection. Please suggest some changes (and amended codes) so that I can resolve the problem.

```
class SampleClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        SampleClass sampleClass = new SampleClass();
        sampleClass.run();
    }

    private void run()
    {
        Task consumer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => WriteDataToFiles());
        GenerateDataFiles();
    }

    BlockingCollection<Dictionary<string, List<string>>> bc = new BlockingCollection<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>();

    private void GenerateDataFiles()
    {
        DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Data\");
        FileInfo[] array_FileInfo = directory.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

        Parallel.ForEach(array_FileInfo, fileInfo => 
        {
            string[] array_Lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileInfo.FullName);

            // do some CPU-intensive data parsing and then add the processed data to the blocking collection
            // It has to be inserted in pairs (key = file path, value = list of strings to be written to this file)

        });
    }

    private void WriteDataToFiles()
    {
        foreach (var item in bc.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            foreach (var key in item.Keys)
            {
                File.WriteAllLines(key, item[key]);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Side note - Writing multiple instances of IO would cause a de-grade in your applications performance, especially when using a mechanical HD. Also, i don't see you inserting any data to the `BlockCollection`.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov The reason why I didn't include codes to insert data to the BlockingCollection is that the syntax I wrote in VS shows error. That's why I left it empty instead of writing something to confuse others.

Comment: Running code in `Parallel.ForEach` will still cause your process to swell because as you're using `File.ReadAllLines` and you're not de-queuing any item from the collection.

Comment: Forget it. Write a sequential version using `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` and `File.ReadLines()`

Comment: The real issue is with your _some CPU-intensive data parsing_, does it need all files and all lines in memory?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Each text file can contain 10,000 to 500,000+ lines. And for each line I need to extract an item for that line and then add that to the list (for writing to a file later on). After that, that line is no longer needed. After reading all the lines in that file, that file is no longer needed. Can you suggest a better approach for me to handle this issue? The reason why I use the File.ReadAllLines() is to minimize the IO needed.

Comment: You are (maybe) saving a little on I/O but spending a lot on Memory. Make sure you understand the difference between `ReadAllLines()` and `ReadLines()`. The better approach is all in my first comment.

Comment: So in this case, the sequential approach is better?

Comment: The sequential approach would probably be better, as your disk won't need to jump through different segments. Also, make sure you read either line by line or a buffer of data each time, not via `ReadAllLines`.

Comment: You seem to be overwriting the input files with the results, is that a (hard) requirement?

Comment: Yes this is a requirement. One of the reasons is I cannot make any changes to the source (input) files, and so I have to write the amended/processed data to separate text files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `Tuple` instead of a `Dictionary` inside the `BlockingCollection`. Additionally, you need a call to `CompleteAdding()` to end the `foreach` in `WriteDataToFiles`.

```
BlockingCollection<Tuple<string, List<string>>> bc = new BlockingCollection<Tuple<string, List<string>>>();

private void GenerateDataFiles()
{
    DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Data\");
    FileInfo[] array_FileInfo = directory.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

    Parallel.ForEach(array_FileInfo, fileInfo => 
    {
        string[] array_Lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileInfo.FullName);

        // do some CPU-intensive data parsing and then add the processed data to the blocking collection
        // It has to be inserted in pairs (key = file path, value = list of strings to be written to this file)
        List<string> processedData = new List<string>();  // ... and add content
        bc.Add(new Tuple<string, List<string>>(fileInfo.FullName, processedData));
    });
    bc.CompleteAdding();
}

private void WriteDataToFiles()
{
    foreach (var tuple in bc.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        File.WriteAllLines(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2);
    }
}
```